# How to work with Git worktree in VS-code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch, git-worktree

Something I'm having a hard time to understand:

how do I work with git worktrees in VS-code ?

I apparently cannot make it work.

I've tried using the command line ... but then when I try to checkout to the desired branch, it tells me:

> Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.longpaths=true -c core.quotepath=false -c color.ui=false checkout sequences --
>
> fatal: 'sequences' is already checked out at

and when I change folder in command line like on so many videos (outside of vs-code) ... it stays with the same branch check-out.

Can somebody help me out or point me to a resource / blog that indicate how to proceed or how to configure to get git worktree working with vs-code ?

Comment: A branch can only be checked out in a single worktree. Find which of your worktree has the branch checked out and switch to another branch.

Answer (score 2):

you can check this issue for your question
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68038
from terminal you can work

##### working with git worktree...

```
git --bare
git worktree list
git worktree add <branch>
git worktree remove <branch>
...
```

#### further...

[https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#:~:text=In%20its%20simplest%20form%2C%20git,at%20path%20..%2Fhotfix%20](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#:%7E:text=In%20its%20simplest%20form%2C%20git,at%20path%20..%2Fhotfix%20).

Comment: thanks to you, I think I identified exactly my issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140790

Comment: I'll probably need to wait the next release to see a difference ... and start being able to use worktrees

Comment: I tried from terminal. Now after creating the worktree, I can navigate to it ... everything seem to work in the command line as expected ... except that the rest of the vs-code display keeps displaying what is on the main branch, and not at all what is in the worktree branch. That is extremely awkward. Do you have a way to switch the focus of the VS-code display on the content of the worktree branch? or do I have to wait for a future release to solve this issue?